# CORS with Firebase+IONIC2+Angularjs: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' still exists

Tags: cors, firebase-storage, proxies

I read all the suggestions and also followed the ionic suggestion how to overcome the CORS issue and get rid of the error: *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* with no success. I think I am missing the exact path conversion in proxies:

**The URL I am trying to access in firebase is:**
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/Test1-xxxxx.appspot.com/o/userData.

**My local host URL is:** localhost:8100.

I don't understand how should I edit the **path** and **proxyUrl** settings in ionic.config.json:

```
{
"name": "Test1", 
"app_id": "", 
"v2": true, 
"typescript": true,

"proxies": [{

  "path": "...",

  "proxyUrl": "..."

}]}
```

I have tried many ways with no success, I am probably missing the point. I am new to Apps in general. I am starting with Web app using angular2+Ionic2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set proxy to

```
 "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/v0",
      "proxyUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0"
    }
  ]
```

Then in your app you should call api as **/v0/b/Test1-xxxxx.appspot.com/o/userData**

Also this is a problem because when you compile it will call the same request meanwhile it should call firebase. So my recommendation would be to add constant **BaseUrl** and in dev it should be empty when you do production set it to "**https://firebasestorage.googleapis.co**" since when you bundle there is no proxy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I struggled this for 3 days! Now it is working! and also I will take your advise regarding BaseUrl. Thanks again!

Comment: In the code, How would you differentiate between the code running via ionic serve...and the code running in firebase?

Comment: @MikeK. Environments or if you are not building native app but progressive then always call /api/myactiton so it will send request to the same domain

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I am building a progressive app, and right now have only been testing it in the web (locally and deployed to firebase).  If my local app calls /api/foo-bar that is fine, since I can use the proxies and have it point to a different URL. But when I'm on firebase, the proxy stuff doesn't work... so wouldn't the APIs then go out to www.my-app.firebase.com/api/foo-bar? Then that wouldn't find anything and return a 404.