# Ionic v2 + CORS Preflight Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, cors

Having issues communicating with an external API via `ionic serve` and `ionic run -l`, essentially anything that uses a localserver.

I've followed the guide @ http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/, which provides an option for handling the issue in Ionic 1 projects, but I'm struggling to get it working in a v2 project.

`Fetch API cannot load https://test.api.promisepay.com/items/100fd4a0-0538-11e6-b512-3e1d05defe79/make_payment. Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.`

I have no control over how the API handles theses requests, as it is controlled by [PromisePay](https://promisepay.com/).

Following the closest thing to a possible solution on StackOverflow: [CORS with Firebase+IONIC2+Angularjs: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' still exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576037/cors-with-firebaseionic2angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-still-exis)

I've updated my `ionic.config.json` to

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "app_id": "xxxxxxx",
  "proxies": [{
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "https://test.api.promisepay.com"
  }]
}
```

In the library that makes the http calls, I've updated the base URL to `const PRE_LIVE_API = '/api';`

The request method looks as follows:

```
let Requester = class Requester {
  constructor() {
    let config = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : {};

    this.config = config;
    const baseUrl = PRE_LIVE_API;
    this.log(`API endpoint: ${ baseUrl }`);
    this.client = _requestPromise2.default.defaults({
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      auth: {
        user: config.userName,
        pass: config.token
      },
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `basic ${ config.apiToken }`
      },
      resolveWithFullResponse: true
    });
  }
```

When making a call to the most basic of API endpoints `/status/` I am now receiving the following error:

`"Error: Invalid URI "/api/status""`

It seems the proxy path isn't being passed through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Explicitly setting the BaseURL constant (PRE_LIVE_BASE) to `http://localhost:8100/api` resolves the issue. Now all requests are passed via the proxy alias and subvert the CORS issue.

The only downside of this approach, is that I had to change a variable that was part of a package in node_modules, which will be overwritten during any future updates. So I should probably create my own fork for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem when I was trying to use the MailGun to send e-mails using REST API.

The solution is to use HTTP instead of http. ionic 2 provides the class [HTTP]: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/http/ .

In your projects root folder, run this command from the terminal:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-http
```

In your .ts file:

```
import { HTTP } from 'ionic-native';
```

Then, wherever you want to send the HTTP post/get using Basic Authentication, use this:

```
HTTP.useBasicAuth(username, password)
//replace username and password with your basic auth credentials
```

Finally, send the HTTP post using this method:

```
HTTP.post(url, parameters, headers)
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For Development purposes where the calling url is http://localhost, the browsers disallow cross-origin requests, but when you build the app and run it in mobile, it will start working.

For the sake of development,
1. Install CORS plugin/Extension in chrome browser which will help get over the CORS issue.
2. If the provider is giving a JSONP interface instead of a normal get/post, You will be able to get over the CORS issue.

I prefer using the 1st option as not a lot of api's provide a jsonP interface.

For Deployment,
You need not worry as building a app & running it in your mobile, you will not face the same issue.

Comment: Strangely enough the standard CORS extension for chrome did not resolve the CORS issue.

Comment: Yes. But then when you try and upload it and use ionicview app, still seem to be having CORS issues there. CORS is my pet hate with Ionic!

Comment: @JGFMK That is because some of the codova plugins donot work inside ionic view..you should check if the cordova-plugin-whitelist which handles the cors in ionic apps is allowed inside the ionic view & whether  you have installed it because as of cordova v4.x the plugin is not added automatically like in previous versions.